# Using/Refresh relational dropdowns

Tags: vba, ms-word, office365

I am trying to set up a dropdown that is dependent on the selection of a previous dropdown in Word using VBA-Code. I watched a bunch of videos and read through forums, but I cannot make it work. I used the Word Legacy dropdowns and labelled them correctly, then I wrote the following code in VBA:

```
    Dim xDirection As FormField
    Dim xState As FormField
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xDirection = ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddType")
    Set xState = ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddSelection")
    If ((xDirection Is Nothing) Or (xState Is Nothing)) Then Exit Sub
    With xState.DropDown.ListEntries
    .Clear
        Select Case xDirection.Result
            Case "Numbers"
                .Add "1"
                .Add "2"
                .Add "3"
                .Add "4"
                .Add "5"
                .Add "6"
            Case "Letters"
                .Add "A"
                .Add "B"
                .Add "C"
            Case "None"
                .Add "Not applicable"
    End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem is that this solution only works sometimes and not consistently. It feels like the possible selections are not updated quick enough and I can choose a letter even if only numbers should be available (sometimes I am not able to select anything at all).

I do this in Office 365.

Feedback will be highly appreciated

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you specify what you want to achieve? To me it is not clear from your question.

Comment: Sure: I want to achieve that I can first make a selection in the dropdown ddType and that the options I have in the dropdown ddSelection will be dependent on that. E.g. If I select "Letters" in the first dropdown I only get to choose from the options "A", "B" and "C" in the following dropdown.

Comment: Would you be fine with content controls as well?

Comment: I am not sure. Content control would restrict me to a certain format, right? I need to have an exact selections of inputs that are possible (eg A, B and C but not D or anything else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: you have a word document with two dropdown content controls.
For both the tag name is set: ccType and ccSelection.

[image]

In the class module of **`ThisDocument`** you put the following code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
If ContentControl.Tag = "ccType" Then
    fillccSelection ContentControl.Range.Text
End If
End Sub

Private Sub fillccSelection(valueType As String)

Dim cc As ContentControl
Set cc = ThisDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("ccSelection")(1)

If cc.Title <> valueType Then
    With cc
        .Title = valueType  'set title to current type so that we now if coming here next time
        .Range.Text = vbNullString  'clear content as it has to change with new values
        With .DropdownListEntries
            .Clear
            Select Case valueType
                Case "Numbers"
                    cc.SetPlaceholderText Text:="Please select a number"
                    .Add "1"
                    .Add "2"
                    .Add "3"

                Case "Letters"
                    cc.SetPlaceholderText Text:="Please select a letter"
                    .Add "A"
                    .Add "B"
                    .Add "C"
            End Select
        End With
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Whenever you change the value of the first content control (ccType) and *exit* it the ContentControlOnExit is fired.

If you "left" ccType (and not ccSelection) fillccSelection is called by passing the value selected in ccType.

If this type is not yet set for ccSelection, the dropdown entries are set according to the selected type.

Comment: Hello Ike, Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I am not able to make it work. I set up the two content control dropdowns and tagged them as you said. I put the code into a module and it still does not work. Am I missing something? Do I have to tie the two dropdowns together in any form so that they communicate? Best, J

Comment: Did you paste the code in the ThisDocument module (step 1)? If you click in the Document_ContentControlOnExit sub (step 2) you should see what is marked 3 and 4 in this screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/Ug9zPPX.png

Comment: Thank you. That solved the first problem. Now I get an Run-Time Error 6124 that seems to originate from the code line ´´´.Range.Text = vbNullString´´´

Comment: I only have a German Word - but please check for `ccSelection` if the highlighted checkbox is **unchecked**: https://i.imgur.com/Fx77qbn.png

Comment: It is unchecked, but the error still tells me that I cannot edit because it is protected. I will have a closer look at the general settings

Comment: When I take out the ".Range.Text = vbNullString" it works perfectly fine, it just does not update the labelling text. However I am fine with that. Thank you very much!